# Can"t fin the origin of Error ; Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, react-native

My App screen. js returns

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Element type is invalid: expected
> a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
> component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
> default and named imports.]

The error does not give me the location of the problem other than the 'render method' can you see where the error is, could you help me find the source of the problem?
Thank you very much

```
import Splash from './src/components/Splash';
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Image,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import MainStackNavigator from "./Navigation/StackNavigator";
import styles from "./assets/styles";
import {
  retrieveAppLang,
  userSessionActive
} from "./src/common/Preferences";
import i18n from "./src/i18n";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
    Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false; 
    this.state = {
      isFirstConnection: true,
      status: 0,

    };
  }

  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    let lang = await retrieveAppLang();
    let isConnected = await userSessionActive();

    if (lang.length == 2) {
      i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
    }

    if (isConnected === true && this.props && this.props.navigation) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("BottomTabNavigator");
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
   
    const data = await this.performTimeConsumingTask();
    if (data !== null) {
      this.setState({
        isFirstConnection: false,
        status: 1,
      });
    }
  }

  performTimeConsumingTask = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("result");
      }, 750)
    );
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.status == 1) {
      if (this.state.isFirstConnection) {
        return <Splash />;
      } else {
        return <MainStackNavigator screenProps={'Authentication'} />;
      }
    }

    return (
        <View style={[styles.container, styles.containerCentered]}>
          <StatusBar hidden={true} />
          <View style={styles.subContainer}>
            <Image
              style={styles.logo}
              source={require("./assets/images/logo.png")}
            />
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#43300E" />
            <Text>{i18n.t("app.loading") + "..."}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Some of the imports are wrong so check them carefully again.

Comment: that's what I thought at first but the pathways are all correct

Comment: is that the 'ScreenProps' from MainStackNavigator that causes this ?

Comment: I would need to see the folder structure to be sure but you can check it.